# Wait Callback and our result data to take another proccess out of this function

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

i have this class (product).

```
        var Product = function () {
        this.products = [];
        this.priceFrom = null;
        this.priceTo = null;
        this.countDone = 0;
    };
    Product.prototype = {
        constructor: Product,

        getProductsByPriceRange: function (priceFrom, priceTo) {
            var xhrUrl = "<?= base_url('market/products/xhr_product_price_range') ?>";
            var xhrData = {price_from: priceFrom, price_to: priceTo};
            var xhrType = "json";

            var UtilsClass = new Utils();
            UtilsClass.xhrConnection(xhrUrl, xhrData, xhrType, function (data) {
                /* MY DATA IS HERE */
            });

        },

        buildList:function (products) {
            for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                var product = products[i];
                console.log("product");
            }
        },

        buildOne: function (product) {

        }
    };

    /*....more classes */
```

And another piece of code (out of product class):

```
var fromPrice = data.from;
                var toPrice = data.to;

                var ProductClass = new Product();

                var lastCountDone = ProductClass.countDone;

                ProductClass.priceFrom = fromPrice;
                ProductClass.priceTo = toPrice;
                var myProducts = ProductClass.getProductsByPriceRange(ProductClass.priceFrom, ProductClass.priceTo);
```

My question is... can i wait callback of UtilsClass.xhrConnection (in first piece) and use generated data of callback in second piece of code (out of first piece).

Any ideas would be very valuable to me. Thank you!

Comment: No, you have to wait in the second piece, but you can return a promise from the first one so that waiting for it is more comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Product = function () {
    this.products = [];
    this.priceFrom = null;
    this.priceTo = null;
    this.countDone = 0;
};
Product.prototype = {
    constructor: Product,

    getProductsByPriceRange: function (priceFrom, priceTo) {
        var xhrUrl = "<?= base_url('market/products/xhr_product_price_range') ?>";
        var xhrData = {price_from: priceFrom, price_to: priceTo};
        var xhrType = "json";

        var UtilsClass = new Utils();
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            UtilsClass.xhrConnection(xhrUrl, xhrData, xhrType, function (data) {
            /* MY DATA IS HERE */
                resolve(data)
             });

        });

    },

    buildList:function (products) {
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            var product = products[i];
            console.log("product");
        }
    },

    buildOne: function (product) {

    }
};
```

While calling,

```
var fromPrice = data.from;
            var toPrice = data.to;

            var ProductClass = new Product();

            var lastCountDone = ProductClass.countDone;

            ProductClass.priceFrom = fromPrice;
            ProductClass.priceTo = toPrice;
            var myProducts = ProductClass.getProductsByPriceRange(ProductClass.priceFrom, ProductClass.priceTo).then(function(data){%your data will be available here%});
```

Comment: You should add a note that the `new Promise` should better be used inside the `UtilsClass.xhrConnection`

Comment: Thank you so much DrEarnest. 
It was just what I needed.